# RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes throws "Unable to load DLL 'BCrypt.dll'"

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have an aws Lambda function that I am making using .NET core. When running the lambda function I get the following error:

> (Unable to load DLL 'BCrypt.dll': The specified module could not be found.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)): AggregateException
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )
>   at Interop.BCrypt.BCryptGenRandom(IntPtr hAlgorithm, Byte* pbBuffer, Int32 cbBuffer, Int32 dwFlags)
>   at Interop.BCrypt.BCryptGenRandom(Byte[] pbBuffer, Int32 cbBuffer)
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(Byte[] data)
>   at User.Util.GetSalt(ILambdaContext context)
>   at User.Functions.d__1.MoveNext()

It is being thrown from the following code:

```
public static string GetSalt()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[128 / 8];

    using(var keyGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        keyGenerator.GetBytes(bytes);
        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

The code is breaking on this line: 
    `keyGenerator.GetBytes(bytes);`

It was my belief that .net core should work well cross platform (As aws uses unix machines).

From everything I can find online this seems to be the best way to do this.

Comment: Did you include `BCrypt.dll` in the package you deployed to lambda?  Lambda won't restore your dependencies on its own.

Comment: yitzih, having the exact same problem for accessing some https. did you manage to find a solution? @Anthony Neace, BCrypt.dll is apparently used by Amazon itself, and it's not even .net core version.. not 100% sure though..

Comment: I believe my issue was due to one of 2 things (I did both of them and I'm not sure which solved the issue for me). 1 - Recreate the program (there may have been an issue with one of the project .json files). 2 - in the lambda-tools-default.json files add the `additional-files` key and reference the dll in "runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard1.6/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll". (see https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/14 for some more information). I believe #2 was how I solved it.